# Is there a simple way to take a thread dump to find cause of thread deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, deadlock

We have an C# console application in production which has intermittent thread deadlock.  I tried to find deadlock by attaching VS 2017 to the running process, but I could not find any way to easily find the cause of the deadlock.  There didn't seem to be any window which identifies which threads are owning which locks. (I tried using the Memory window, but that didn't work at all).

I have also tried using Dump file but found it very hard to make sense of what it shows. (But this was before I knew I was searching for a deadlock.)

I am used to using JStack in Java, a command line utility to run against running Java application, which prints a Thread dump, and identifies deadlocks, and shows in each StackTrace the points where a Thread has locked a monitor.

Is there some equivalent tool for .NET?

Comment: The question as it stands is off-topic for the site as it is requesting an off site resource/tool. However, if you could minimise the code into a [MCVE] and post that instead, I believe the question should be fine. By doing that you are also likely to find the reason it is dead locking yourself. Side note, log tools such as log4net print the thread id when configured correctly, this can help you find the reason it is locking if you have sufficient logging in place.

Comment: Don't you have exactly the same information in .NET? Call stack for each thread...(there are libraries, GUI and CL apps to do it if you don't want/can't to attach VS)

Comment: If you attach to the running process from Visual Studio 2015, then you should be able to 'pause' and to open something called 'Parallel Stacks' (from the main menu select Debug / Windows / Parallel Stacks)  
I do not know is that available in VS2017, but I have used that feature several times so far and it helped me a lot.

Comment: OP: I recommend you remove the line that asks for a "tool" and replace it with "how to find the deadlock".

Comment: @xxbbcc Asking how to find the deadlock will then be closed as too broad or why isn't this code working....

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Hey, if you're bending out of shape to close something, nothing's going to change that.

Comment: @xxbbcc I'm not I'm following the close reasons, anyway time to move on with my life...

Comment: @xxbbcc It's not bending *anything* out of shape, it's just not actively ignoring the close reasons and pretending that they don't exist.  Just because you're knowingly and intentionally violating the rules doesn't mean everyone else is going to.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: I don't really understand your comment.  This is a large application.  Would be great if I could boil down the *several thousand lines of code* to a minimal, verifiable example.  If I could do that, I certainly wouldn't need to ask the question.  But I wouldn't have anything resembling the application either.  BTW- this is a .NET technology question.  Either a tool exists or doesn't exist.  Tool questions are not out of scope.

Comment: @SamGoldberg They quite clearly are, check the close reason...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Dude, have you read the Help Center link yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic? It says:  "but if your question generally covers…

    a specific programming problem, or
    a software algorithm, or
    *software tools commonly used by programmers*; and is
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"  (My emphasis added).

Comment: @SamGoldberg Yes it covers the use of the tools, it however does not cover tool suggestions. See the closure reason: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use WinDbg to examine a full userdump taken from the process when the deadlock happens. Make sure you have the exact binaries (DLL-s and PDB-s) along with the dump file. Use the appropriate WinDbg version for your binaries (32-bit or 64-bit).

Open your dump using the `File`->`Open crash dump...` command, this will open a "console" window in WinDbg. You use it by typing commands in the bottom input area. You can save all WinDbg output by logging it in the `Edit` menu.

You can load the SOS extension using `.loadby sos clr` and then get all the call stacks using `!EEStack`. You can try using the `-short` parameter to see if you spot the same function on top of the threads.

As @dmitry-egorov suggested in the comments, you can also use the `!dlk` from SOSEX.

When you're looking for functions that may cause the deadlock, look for *your* functions - they may not be at the very top of the stack but will be close - some of your functions are likely trying to take 2 different locks in different orders and they deadlock.

[Here's some documentation about how to use WinDbg.](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html)

Comment: I'd assume someone with your reputation on the site should know better than to answer a tool request question...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I don't see this as a "tool" question - if someone is trying to troubleshoot a very particular (and hard) problem on an unfamiliar platform, that's not the same as asking for "what's the best free library...". (Only my opinion, you obviously disagree.) Not all problems have nice reproducible code snippets.

Comment: How is `Is there some equivalent tool for .NET?` not asking for a tool request? And yes they are trying to troubleshoot it but have no code here so have only requested for a tool to help them. The circumstances surrounding the question doesn't change the question.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Have you ever tried finding a deadlock in a code base that's over a million lines of source code long? How would you create an MVCE out of that? You can fake up an example but that won't be _your_ problem that you need to fix - it's just a fake example that only creates noise.

Comment: I have and sometimes removing code makes the problem easier, not always though. Also there is nothing in the OP to suggest there code is millions of lines long.

Comment: Also, check out `!dlk` from SOSEX extension (see [short](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mohamedg/2010/01/28/how-to-debug-deadlocks-using-windbg/) and [long](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXANewDebuggingExtensionForManagedCode.aspx) posts on the topic) for detecting deadlock in managed code and `!locks` for [unmanaged deadlocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540592(v=vs.85).aspx)